# Updating to Angular2.0.0-rc.1, can't get past this error

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs, angular2-routing

App refuses to find `symbol-observable` - or zone.js does - even though rxjs is definitely in there.

[image: error]

Got everything loading like:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script>
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
  },
  packages: {
    'dist': { defaultExtension: 'js', format: 'register', main: 'boot.js' },
    '@angular/common': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
    '@angular/compiler': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
    '@angular/core': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
    '@angular/http': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
    '@angular/platform-browser': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
    '@angular/router': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  }
});
System.import('dist').catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I put all the code up [here](https://github.com/RyanMetin/slush-angular2/tree/rc1) for a closer look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried mapping to `symbol-observable` again. It worked this time. Go figure.

```
System.config({
  map: {
    ...,
    'symbol-observable': 'node_modules/symbol-observable'
  },
  packages: {
    ...,
    'symbol-observable': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's likely due to rxjs beta.7. Downgrading to beta.6 in your package.json should resolve the problem.

```
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
```

there is issue from  angular team [issue](https://github.com/IgorMinar/new-world-test/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the exact error in the first post in this thread popped up in my project. I fixed it by adding this in packages.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "symbol-observable": "^0.2.4",
  ...
}
```

and executing npm install afterwards.

In systemjs.config.js I added the following:

```
var map = {
  ...
  'symbol-observable': 'node_modules/symbol-observable'
  ...
};

var packages = {
  ...
  'symbol-observable': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  ...
};
```